# Angular momentum of the vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, vacuum, dirac-equation, spinors

I'm studying quantum field theory from "An introduction to Quantum field theory" by Peskin and Schroeder and from "A modern introduction to quantum field theory" by Maggiore. I've read from "An introduction to Quantum field theory", on page 61, that $J_{z} |0>=0$. However, computing the angular momentum and performing the normal ordering, I arrive to the equation:
\begin{eqnarray}
J_{z} &=& \int{\frac{d^3x d^3p d^3p'}{(2 \pi)^6\sqrt{4 E_{\textbf{p}} E_{\textbf{p}'}}}}  e^{-ip'x}e^{ipx} \nonumber \\ &\times&\sum_{r,r'}(a_{\textbf{p}'}^{r'\dagger}u^{r'\dagger}(\textbf{p}')+b^{r'}_{-\textbf{p}'}v^{r'\dagger}(-\textbf{p}'))\frac{\Sigma^3}{2}(a_{\textbf{p}}^{r\dagger}u^{r\dagger}(\textbf{p})+b^{r}_{-\textbf{p}}v^{r\dagger}(-\textbf{p})) \nonumber \\
&=& \int{\frac{d^3p d^3p'}{(2 \pi)^3\sqrt{4 E_{\textbf{p}} E_{\textbf{p}'}}}}  e^{i(E_{\textbf{p}}-E_{\textbf{p}'})t}e^{-i(\textbf{p}-\textbf{p})\cdot\textbf{x}} \nonumber \\ &\times&\sum_{r,r'}(a_{\textbf{p}'}^{r'\dagger}u^{r'\dagger}(\textbf{p}')+b^{r'}_{-\textbf{p}'}v^{r'\dagger}(-\textbf{p}'))\frac{\Sigma^3}{2}(a_{\textbf{p}}^{r\dagger}u^{r\dagger}(\textbf{p})+b^{r}_{-\textbf{p}}v^{r\dagger}(-\textbf{p})) \nonumber \\
 &=&\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3 2 E_{\textbf{p}}} \nonumber \\ &\times&\sum_{r,r'} (a_{\textbf{p}}^{r'\dagger}u^{r'\dagger}(\textbf{p})+b^{r'}_{-\textbf{p}}v^{r'\dagger}(-\textbf{p}))\frac{\Sigma^3}{2}(a_{\textbf{p}}^{r\dagger}u^{r\dagger}(\textbf{p})+b^{r}_{-\textbf{p}}v^{r\dagger}(-\textbf{p})) \nonumber \\
&=& \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3 2 E_{\textbf{p}}} \nonumber \\ &\times&\sum_{r,r'} (a_{\textbf{p}}^{r' \dagger} a_{\textbf{p}}^{r} u^{r'\dagger}(\textbf{p})\frac{\Sigma^3}{2}u^{r}(\textbf{p})+a_{\textbf{p}}^{r'\dagger}b_{-\textbf{p}}^{r \dagger}u^{r'\dagger}(\textbf{p})\frac{\Sigma^3}{2} v^r(-\textbf{p}) \nonumber \\ &+& b^{r'}_{-\textbf{p}}a_{\textbf{p}}^r v^{r'\dagger}(-\textbf{p}) \frac{\Sigma^3}{2} u^r(\textbf{p})+b^{r'}_{-\textbf{p}}b^{r \dagger}_{-\textbf{p}}v^{r' \dagger}(- \textbf{p})\frac{\Sigma^3}{2} u^r(-\textbf{p})). \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
After normal ordering, applying $J_{z}$ to $|0>$, the first, third and fourth terms are indeed zero. The second term however becomes
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3  E_{\textbf{p}}} \sum_{r,r'} u^{r'\dagger}(\textbf{p})\frac{\Sigma^3}{2} v^r(-\textbf{p})a_{\textbf{p}}^{r'\dagger}b_{-\textbf{p}}^{r \dagger}|0>. \nonumber
\end{equation}
And I don't understand how it becomes zero.
Thank you.

Comment: Assuming your algebra is correct, it seems to me that the only way it would vanish is if $u^{r'}({\bf p}) \Sigma^3 v^r(-{\bf p}) = 0$. Did you check this?

Comment: I tried to check that equation, but I found it quite hard.